# Can I send a param to the delete method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

So this is the scenario:

In the show view for my Partner model I need a link_to a delete method for another model, my RecommendPartner model.

But I need to return to my Partner show after the destroy method finishes.

To the code!!

My Partner show view (if this is terribly ugly I accept suggestions):

```
  <div>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy!', @partner.recommended?(current_user), confirm: 'Are your sure?', method: 'delete', :controller => "recommend_partners", :action => "destroy", :p_id => @partner.id  %>
  </div>
```

As you see I am trying to send a :p_id to the params, but with no success.

Here's my recommended? method in case you need to know, it just returns a RecommendPartner object. In my Partner.rb:

```
def recommended? (user)
  RecommendPartner.find_by_user_id_and_partner_id(user.id,self.id)
end
```

Yes, RecommendPartner belongs to user and partner models.

Finally here's my recommend_partners_controler destroy method:

```
def destroy
  @recommend_partner = RecommendPartner.find(params[:id])
  partner = Partner.find(params[:p_id])
  @recommend_partner.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to partner }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

So params[:p_id] is nil and I can't redirect back to the partner show that I was... =/

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. What's the point of doing `partner = Partner.find(params[:p_id])` if you can `partner = @recommend_partner.partner` and not pass any p_id at all? 2. Why not use named route (you can find them by running `rake routes`) instead of `controller: ..., action: ...` hash?

Comment: The reason I did not use named routes was because of the param id!!
Very stupid of me since I can get the partner from the recommend_partner object like you said! Thanks @hakunin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks to @hakunin's comment this is the best solution

Change the controller so that I won't need the p_id param:

```
  def destroy
    @recommend_partner = RecommendPartner.find(params[:id])
    @partner = @recommend_partner.partner
    @recommend_partner.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @partner }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

And then modify the link_to method to look like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy!', @partner.recommended?(current_user), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
```

Works Great!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?:

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy!', partner_path(@partner.recommended?(current_user), 'p_id' => @partner.id), :method => 'delete', :confirm => 'Are your sure?' %>
```

Comment: Since I modified the controller so that I wouldn't need the p_id, I just called it like this:
`<%= link_to 'Destroy!', @partner.recommended?(current_user), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>`

It works fine!